# How to pass JSON array in body of web api c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am trying to capture a JSON array of string from POST Request in web api.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CancelItems([FromBody] List<string> items)
{
    //codes
}
```

But I am getting null in items.

Post Body:

```
{
    "items":[
        "1034908029943809497", "1034908029943809494"
    ]

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried pls? There are many ways to create a post request

Comment: Your json body is not compatible with your code model.

Create c# model with inner property 'List<string> items' and pass to endpoint or modify request body: remove nested element items, use [] instead of

Comment: @Serge, the code doesn't matter, I am just getting items null :)

Comment: Code is the most important, this is why you are getting items null

Comment: Learn [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)! Why doesn't anyone do this? / `{}` means `object`, not `array`/`list`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to capture a JSON array of string from POST Request in web
> api.

Based on your shared code snippet, It has appreared that you want to get your items array on your web api controller.

Apparently, two context need to clarify here, either API controller need to construct as per your request Definition or request Definition need to modify based on your API.

**Way: 1:** Define API based on request body:

Considering your request body which is strongly type of items object so based on this if you want to send request as per your current requst body; Thus, a strongly type POCO class need to be introduced.

Let's take a look in action.

Strongly Type Model:

```
public class StringCompatibleClass
    {

        public List<string> items { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CancelItems([FromBody] StringCompatibleClass items)
        {
            return Ok(items);
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Way: 2:** Modify request body based on API Definition:

Based on your current API Definition if you prefer to persist with API defination as it is then you would require to change request body as following which alrady shown by another contributor:

```
[
        "1034908029943809497", "1034908029943809494"
]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just send the `strings`:

```
[
    "1034908029943809497", "1034908029943809494"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller's method is expecting json array and you request has jsonnode body. If you don't want to change controller then change post body like [ "1034908029943809497", "1034908029943809494"].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CancelItems([FromBody] JObject jObject)
{
      var model = jObject.ToObject<FromQuery>();
      //replace FromQuery with your model class
      //code ....
}
```